# How to scale an object along its length

Tags: transforms, geometry-nodes

Does somebody know how to control the scale of an object along its length?

I'm trying to control the scale along the length using the float curve node to set values.

However in my setup I'm only able to control the scale of the whole object.

My problem is that in this setup the scale is being control only by the furthers right point of the float curve node.

[image: node setup]

This is what I'm trying to get, but I can't figure it out how to:

[image: object profile]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could solve this as follows:

[image]

First capture the dimensions of the object with `Bounding Box`.

Then map the Z-axis to a range from $0$ to $1$ and put this value into the node `Float Curve`.

With this result you can scale the position vector and use it as *Offset* in combination with the node `Set Position`.

[image]
<sub>*(Blender 3.1+)*</sub>

Comment: Thank you!!!!!!

Comment: @LuizAntonio You are welcome!